# How do I save error message from console?

Tags: log

My laptop crashes ([which is another question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61713/computer-crashes-segfaults-after-upgrading-from-1gb-ram-to-2gb)) and when it does so it swiches to a text console and outputs an error which is too long to type ([like this](http://paste.ubuntu.com/691805/)). I can't do anything with it other than sometimes restart X (otherwise restart the computer) when it crashes. Is there any way I can get this error so I can post it? A log somewhere?
I've tried SSH and conspy, but networking seems to get cut off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I was able to get this specfic error by ssh'ing in and running

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog
```

.

Answer (score 1):

If you can restart X, then it is X that's crashing, not the computer. Look at your X logs in `/var/log/Xorg*`.

Answer (score 1):

If you start a new X session, the message you are looking for is probably in `/var/log/Xorg.0.log.old` I suggest you paste the entire file (it's a long paste) and not the part that looks relevant to you.